# Creating a Snap.svg object from an <object> element

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

The documentation for Snap.svg's `Snap()` function lists three possible ways of creating a Snap object.

- `Snap(width, height)` - Creates a new, blank canvas of given dimensions.
- `Snap(svg element)` - Create a Snap canvas from an existing, inline SVG element
- `Snap(css selector)` - Same as above, but with a selector rather than a direct reference

Is it possible to create a Snap object from either an SVG embedded as either an`<object>` element or a `<img>`?

Comment: Not sure of a way, but is loading the svg in via Snaps load function not a possibility ? A bit more context of the limitations may give some possible ideas.

Comment: You're correct, creating a blank canvas with `Snap()` and then loading  the external SVGs with `snap.load()` would probably work. This would mean loading the SVG twice though, once embedded in the page (because the SVG still needs to be visible without Snap.svg) and then again with `snap.load()`.

Comment: Couldn't you place the svg inside the other markup and use it then ? Like http://jsfiddle.net/f8Sh8/1/ its tricky as I mentioned without knowing what you actually need to do and why (ie why you need to use Snap).

Comment: Technically yes, the svgs could be embedded. This is tricky though, our templating system doesn't have access to the frontend image files where the svgs are stored. So whilst that is a potential solution I'd rather avoid it because it would involve something like duplicating the svgs in the template directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I can come up with that may sort of work, is using something like the object tag, with contentDocument (may need to check support, but Snap isn't really aimed at old browsers anyway).

I think the svg image will have to be local to the file though, so remote calls to images I don't think would work (or maybe with some amended server settings), so I couldn't get it working on a fiddle to show, just with a test url below, so the code would be something like...

in html...

```
<object id="tux" data="Dreaming_Tux.svg" width="600" height="600" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

then js....

```
var tux = Snap("#tux");
var tuxContent = tux.node.contentDocument;   /// grab the referenced content

var sTux = Snap( tuxContent.firstChild );    /// snapify it
var tuxPaths = sTux.selectAll('path');       /// use snaps selector to grab elements

tuxPaths.forEach( function( el ) { el.attr({ opacity: 0.2 }) });
```

[testing example here](http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-embed.html)

Answer (score 2):

By peering at the source-code, I think just doing a `Snap('#object-id')` would give you the SVG, instead of doing `.node.contentDocument`. This may be a recent improvement, but as of today, this is officially there in the code.

Here's the supporting source code: https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/blob/5b17fca57cbc4f8a8fd9ddd55cea2511da619ecf/dist/snap.svg.js#L3182-L3184

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to use Snap's `Element.node` with an `<object>` tag if you are serving the svg from the same domain. E.g. you can't use it from a file system, you have to set up a local server (same-origin policy).

If you have

```
<object id="graph" data="somevectors.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Then you can just use this

```
var s = Snap(Snap("#graph").node); //wrap the element
```

Then select the svg elements with CSS selectors and mess around with them

```
var circle = s.select("#circle")
   .attr({
      opacity: .3
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

@kumar_harsh is right. That's being said, I couldn't get it to work due to page loading problems. Even inside a window.onload callback, `Snap('#object-id')` came back null or returned the object tag with nothing inside.

To use a simple `Snap('#object-id')`, I had to use the method demonstrated in the documentation [here](http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-load-animate):

1) substitute the object tag with an empty svg tag (`#object-id` -> `#svg-id`)

2) var `s = Snap(#svg-id)`

3) Load in the svg elements using `Snap.load('/path/to/my/svg.svg')`

4) In the load callback function `s.append(resultData)`;

5) Use Snap

If your code works in your browsers console, but not live, then you might be encountering the same problem, and your solution is above.